# what does "(.+)"}], in lua pattern matching mean

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

i got this code that take webhook message but i dont understand the pattern matching behind it

```
function getContent(link)
    cmd = io.popen('powershell -command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Write-Host (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "'..link..'").Content"')
    return cmd:read("*all"):match('"description": "(.+)"}],')
end

function blabla(a)
    link= webhookLink.."/messages/"..messageId
    text = [[
        $webHookUrl = "]]..link..[["
        $embedObject = @{
            description = "]]..getContent(link):gsub("\\([nt])", {n="\n", t="\t"})..[[`n]]..a..[["
        }
        $embedArray = @($embedObject)
        $payload = @{
            embeds = $embedArray
        }
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $webHookUrl -Body ($payload | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4) -Method Patch -ContentType 'application/json'
    ]]
    file = io.popen("powershell -command -", "w")
    file:write(text)
    file:close()
end
```

My question is what does `"(.+)"}]` mean in the `getContent` function and `]]..getContent(link):gsub("\\([nt])", {n="\n", t="\t"})..[[n]]..a..[[` in `blabla` function ?

Comment: it is all in the manual. what stops you from reading it?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break up the pattern: `"description": "(.+)"}],`

- `"description": "` - literal string that needs to match
- `(.+)` - one or more of any character, greedy (`+`), captured
- `"}],` - another literal string

That is, this pattern will match the first substring that starts with `"description": "`, followed by one or more characters which are captured, followed by `"}],`.

All in all, this pattern is a very unreliable implementation of extracting a certain string from what's probably JSON; **you should use a proper JSON parser instead**. This pattern will fail in all of the following cases:

- Empty String: `[[{"description": ""}],null]` (might be intended)
- Another String later on: `[{"foo": [{"description": "bar"}], "baz": "world"}], null]`, which would match as `bar"}], "baz": "world` due to `+` doing greedy matching.

Comment: ahh okay why + is greedy ? also ]]..getContent(link):gsub("\\([nt])", {n="\n", t="\t"})..[[n]]..a..[[

for this iam trying to dechiper also what pattern is that matching

Comment: `+` is greedy per definition. Refer to the [reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1). `\([nt])` matches a backslash followed by an `n` or `t`, which is captured (JSON string escapes). `str:gsub("\([nt])", {n="\n", t="\t"})` will replace the escape sequence `\n` with a newline character and the escape sequence `\t` with a tab.

Answer (score 1):

https://gitspartv.github.io/lua-patterns/
This can help you greatly with pattern matching,

though, (.+) means capture any digit, with multiple repetations.

example: "ABC(.+)" would return everything after "ABC"

`return cmd:read("*all"):match('"description": "(.+)"}],')`
Looks like this gets everything inside `description: "THIS_IS_RETURNED"],`

Answer (score -1):

`.` means any character, and `+` means one or more. I suggest you to read up on the basics of patterns. For example: http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial